# Existence of subset of reals such that any real number is unique sum of exactly two elements of the subset

Tags: set-theory

It is easy to see (using AC, of course) that there exist two sets $U\subset\mathbb{R}$ and $V\subset\mathbb{R}$ such that any real number $x$ can be represented as unique sum $x=u+v$, where $u\in U$ and $v\in V$.
There are $2^{2^\omega}$ such $(U,V)$ pairs.

The question given by my son: prove existence of pair $(U,V)$ with $U=V$.

In other words, prove the existence of $U\subset\mathbb{R}$ such that for any $x\in\mathbb{R}$ there exists unique pair $\{u,v\}$ with $x=u+v$

Comment: If $(u,v)$ works, then so does $(v,u)$, so there's hardly ever a unique pair.

Comment: @GerryMyerson: Thank you. I have corrected the error.

Comment: As you've written it as a set, we are insisting $u\ne v$?

Comment: No. They can be equal. Sorry for my inaccuracy. Corrected.

Comment: My point was, if $u=v$, then $\{\,u,v\,\}=\{\,u\,\}$ isn't a pair, it's a singleton.

Comment: But singleton by one of definitions is a pair $\{u,v\}$ with $u=v$ :-)

Comment: Why isn't the answer as simple as the union of U and V that you've shown do exist? It is because it must necessarily be a proper subset?

Comment: The union will also be proper subset, but we loss uniquity.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The usual transfinite construction works. Let $\{r_{\alpha} : \alpha < \mathfrak{c}\}$ list $\mathbb{R}$. Construct $\{U_{\alpha}: \alpha < \mathfrak{c}\}$ by induction on $\alpha$ such that the following hold.

(a) For every $a, b, c, d \in U_{\alpha}$, $a + b = c + d \implies \{a, b\} = \{c, d\}$.

(b) There are $a, b \in U_{\alpha + 1}$ such that $r_{\alpha} = a + b$.

(c) For limit $\alpha$, $U_{\alpha} = \bigcup_{\beta < \alpha} U_{\beta}$.

Then $U = \bigcup_{\alpha < \mathfrak{c}} U_{\alpha}$ is as required. Requirements (a), (c) are trivially satisfied. To ensure (b), at stage $\alpha + 1$, if $r_{\alpha} \notin U + U$, choose $x$ outside the $\mathbb{Q}$-linear span of $U_{\alpha} \cup \{r_{\alpha}\}$ and put $U_{\alpha+1} = U_{\alpha} \cup \{x, r_{\alpha} - x\}$ and note that this does not violate (a).

Comment: This is essentially the argument we use in our paper, specified to the torsion-free case. Things get a little subtler when torsion is present.

Comment: Thank you. So, the simple proof exists! I'll only add that $\mathbb{Q}$-linear span of $U_\alpha\cap\{r_\alpha\}$ can not be equal to $\mathbb{R}$ because $|\alpha| < |c|$.

Answer (score 10):

Sets $U$ with this property are sometimes called *perfect additive bases*. As shown in the paper of Sergei Konyagin and myself "[The Erdos-Turan problem in infinite groups](http://math.haifa.ac.il/seva/Papers/ErTur.pdf)", any infinite abelian group $G$ with $|2G|=|G|$ possesses such a basis, unless $G$ is the direct sum of a group of exponent $3$ and the group of order $2$. (The condition $|2G|=|G|$ essentially means that $G$ does not have "too many" involutions.)

Comment: Thank you for quick and exact answer. I am reading your article right now. But may be there exist some simple answer in case of $\mathbb{R}$, because the problem was given to first-year student of MIPT.

Comment: @ar.grig: The *answer* is quite simple even in the general case, but as to a simple *argument* - well, if you manage to find one, I would be very much interested to learn about it.

Comment: Yes, of course, I mean simple proof. One was given by Mike. Thank you.